# npm install private git+ssh repositories by dependency in package.json

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I've got several local (private) modules that I'm trying to set up to be installable directly from a git repository from any local user's machine.

I can already set it up so if the files are first cloned (e.g. via git) to the local machine I can "npm install" the top-level module and all the other dependencies will be figured out and installed.  I do this by doing something like:

```
apt-get install /path/to/top/top/level/module
```

and then as all packages are under the same top-level directory, in each `package.json` setting the dependencies to a relative path, e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
    "another-module": "../another-module"
}
```

However, it isn't always desirable to have to have a local copy of the source on the machine before it gets installed.  With a lot of packages it would be only a bit more work to just manually "npm install" all the dependencies in the right order manually rather than cloning each project with git. The goal, then, is to use something like:

```
npm install git+ssh://user@somehow.local/home/user/git/another-module
```

It is still possible to have this working using dependencies, now changing the above to something like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "another-module": "git+ssh://user@somehow.local/home/user/git/another-module"
}
```

But this is very brittle.  If any of the details of the server changes, every single dependency must be changed.  Further, it prevents the possibility of multiple different locations to choose from - everything is locked into a single location at a time.  In fact, it even prevents different users on the same machine who all have access to the repository from accessing it because each one has a different "user@" portion of the URL!

If I use the relative path per the original dependencies that doesn't work - it instead tries to interpret that as being relative to the directory I'm installing in, and of course that directory doesn't exist yet!

How can I install git+ssh repositories and retain the dependencies properly, without tying them to a specific location or user?  Is there perhaps some way to use an environment variable in package.json, so I could do something like this?

```
"dependencies": {
    "another-module": "${PRIVATE_NPM_ROOT}/another-module"
}
```